# Making gameobjects load and an active loadingscreen run at the same time

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make it so I can load meshes into my scene on the main thread, whilst actively displaying UI and not halting the program. Unity doesn't have a UI thread for what I can see, how do I draw to the screen while loading GameObjects in the main thread?

All of the Unity API is locked to the MainThread. I've considered making an action queue and calling them one by one, but there are far too many calls for it to just work sub-optimally. I've doing everything but the API calls outside of the main thread but the API calls are what is getting the application caught.

Comment: Use the [Jobs system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JobSystem.html).

Comment: I need to draw to the screen during the job though. How would I do that?

Comment: I've only looked at the Jobs system briefly myself, so I don't have a good idea of how it works. As for drawing to the screen, I don't think you're approaching that in the right way. Drawing happens every frame, if you want something to be drawn, you should query it from the child thread's data (child thread writes, main thread reads) and do it from the main thread. I assume you want something like a progress bar.